# Navigation issues jQuery CSS HTML

Tags: jquery, html, css, navigation

I have been trying to build this nav for weeks now and something always go wrong.

What I am trying to do is have primary-nav and when you over over the primary-nav, the secondary-nav will appear below it and a little to the right. If you hover off the primary-nav or secondary-nav, the secondary-nav will display:none.

You can see this at http://willruppelglass.com/index.php

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="headerNav">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>

<li class="primary-nav-item"><a href="#" class='galleryNavToggle'>Gallery</a>
<ul style="display:none;">
<li><a href="#">Categoies</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

<li class="primary-nav-item"><a href="#" class='galleryNavInfoToggle'>Info</a>
<ul style="display:none;">
<li><a href="#">F.A.Q.</a></li>
<li><a href="#">CV</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Artist Bio</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Video</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

</ul>
</div>
```

MY CSS

```
.headerNav{
    color:#000;
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 1280px;
    padding-top: 148px;
}

.headerNav ul{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0 0 0 8px;
}

.headerNav li{
    float:left;
}

.headerNav ul a{
    font-size:24px;
    color:#FFF;
    display:block;
    padding:0 55px 0 0;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:capitalize;

}

.headerNav ul a:hover{
    color:#a40404;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.headerNav ul ul li {
    float: left;   
}

.headerNav ul ul a {
    font-size: 16px;
    display:block;        
}
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.headerNav li.primary-nav-item').hover(
            function() { $('ul', this).css('display', 'block'); },
            function() { $('ul', this).css('display', 'none'); });
    });
```

Other notes, I have two divs below the nav, which could why its not displaying, can I get it to overlay those divs?

```
<div class="headerDropShadow"></div><!--headerDropShadow-->

<div class="contentWrapper">
<div class="content" id="content">
<div class="topContent"></div><!--topContent-->
</div>
</div>
```

and their respected CSS

```
.headerDropShadow{
    background:url(../images/headerShadow.jpg) repeat-x;
    width:100%;
    height:49px;
}

.topContent{
    background:url(../images/topContent.jpg) repeat-x;
    width: 992px;
    height:50px;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
}
```

Any help at all would be great as this as been an issue for a loooooong time.

Thanks in advanced,
J

Comment: Um, what's the problem you're having?

Comment: What's with CAPS ALL OVER THE PLACE!?

Comment: if u take a look at http://willruppelglass.com/index.php you will notice if u hover over gallery, there is a massive space between that and info and the secondary-nav doesnt show up at all

Comment: you need to write a sentence like "the problem I have is that X happens, when I really want Y to happen"...

Comment: The problem is when I hover over a primary-item, there is space created between the primary-items and the secondary-items doesnt appear, I am excepting when you hover over a primary-item the secondary-items assiocated with the primary-items is appear below the primary-item and to the right a little bit. And when you hover off the primary-item or the assiocated secondary-items the secondary-item display:none, I hope this makes sence, Im just soo soo tired

Comment: Made something like this a while ago... css/html only; could be enhanced with jQuery to work pre IE7, by default shows the sub items in the active category or the subitems of the menu item it hovers over on hover: http://jsfiddle.net/EGNKE/74/

Comment: Aside from the menu I really hope you're going to optimize those images for the web at some point; their loading times are atrocious amd you're using 2000x2000px photos as thumbnails >.<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.headerNav li ul {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

I would also recommend using .clearfix hack for the parent ul element. More info about clearfix here: http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/.
In jquery try to use .toggle(), just because it need less code ^^.

Answer (score 0):

For starters:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .headerNav ul { position: relative; z-index: 10000; }
    .headerNav ul ul li { overflow: hidden; }
</style>
```

Don't completely replace what you have - just add those properties, then at least you'll be able to see what you can't currently. Then you can start to figure out whats going on with the JS.

---

More edits

```
li.primary-nav-item { position: relative; }
li.primary-nav-item ul { position: absolute; top: 32px; width: 600px; }
```

That should get you close enough to where you want to be to finish.

Comment: I just updated http://willruppelglass.com/index.php but removing a margin-top:-48px in a class called .content, now you can see it the secodary nav, how do I get it go over top of the .content class, but the .content class needs to be where it is.